# looking for help call a perl script with arguments from java class

Tags: java, perl, perl-module

I have to call a Perl script from a Java class. I am able to do that using

```
final ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("perl", "/home/abc.pl");
```

I am wondering if I can pass parameters something like

```
new ProcessBuilder("perl", "/home/abc.pl  x y");
```

But it's throwing an error.

Could someone please suggest how this could be done?

Comment: **What** error is it throwing?

Comment: can not find the abc.pl x y. if i remove the args it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html):

> `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");`

Each argument to the program you are calling needs to be a separate argument to the ProcessBuilder constructor.

```
new ProcessBuilder("perl", "/home/abc.pl", "x", "y");
```

Otherwise you are calling the equivalent of `perl "/home/abc.pl x y"` and it will be unable to find a file called "/home/abc.pl x y" (since x and y are different arguments, not part of the file name).

Comment: great help Quentin.. Many thanks for the quick reply and your time.

Answer (score 2):

Use following code to execute your perl code from java.

```
final List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();                

commands.add("perl");
commands.add("/home/abc.pl");
commands.add("x");
commands.add("y");
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
```